# How to create and set process as windows service?

Tags: windows, windows-services

I have a long command with several parameters that I have to run every time windows box is restarted. What is the simple way to set it as windows service so it can be set to automatic restart after system reboot.

Comment: Windows services are not designed for that (it will stay in memory after the work is done). Better looking at `Run` registry entries or the boot-time trigger for the task scheduler.

Comment: Can we use in-built tool SC.exe in win 10 to achieve that?